# strange behavior with Turkish language setting

Tags: sql-server-2005, query, sql-server-2000

I have database with Collation Arabic_CI_AS

when I have windows with English settings I can do

```
select Column from Table where Column= 'A'
```

and can do

```
select column from table where column= 'A'
```

I mean the naming is not case sensitive

In Turkish windows

if any of the names not as named in the DB it raise error in my windows application

I mean that in Turkish windows the names must be case sensitive

any  idea to explain that and how to solve it such that I don't face it again in any language settings

Comment: I did the update

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your application and test it on a case sensitive server, there is no workaround. Asking all your customers to deploy on case insensitive server collations is not the answer. Fix your code, don't break your customers.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server will treat SQL scripts as being case sensitive if the database has a case sensitive collation.  I know one outfit that uses something like Polish binary in a test environment specifically to test for this.

As to why your Arabic collation is treating latin characters as case sensitive, I'm not sure.

EDIT: What is the default server collation - is the default collation case sensitive or binary?